# Lua/love2d - Pathing to assets folder for game

Tags: lua, directory, path, love2d

I have an assets folder that I'm attempting to path to obtain my video game background

I've tried many variations of

```
Background = love.graphics.newImage(C:\Users\"pc name"\Desktop\SpaceshipGame\assets\"spacey.png")

Background = love.graphics.newImage(...\Spaceshipgame\assets\"spacey.png")

etc

C:\Users\"my pc name"\Desktop\SpaceshipGame\assets
```

what is the best way to path from `SpaceshipGame->assets->spacey.png`

if have any question ask away

Comment: Is there any trace of failure  ?  i would set image path fully between " and relative to root directory of projet ie something like Background = love.graphics.newImage("assets\spacey.png")

Comment: or using '/' separator instead of '\' : "assets/spacey.png"

Comment: '\' should be escaped, then replaced by '\\'

Answer (score 0):

First of all use `/` instead of `\`. Also you should have apostrophes around the directory as a whole and not separately around the image file name.

This code should work:

```
Background = love.graphics.newImage('assets/spacey.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and simplest path is simply:

```
Background = love.graphics.newImage("assets/spacey.png")
```

As long as the "assets" folder is in your project folder (The folder which contains your main.lua, etc) this will work.

Hope this helped!